# Find second maximum, but not second largest number, in array

Tags: python, max

I would like to find the second maximum, which is not necessarily the second largest number, in an array or list. As an example, see the array and graph below.

I would like to find the second maximum, which is located at a depth of 40 m and has a value of 8. Just using the criterion to find the maximum below a certain depth doesn't work for me, because this depth of the second maximum is varying in space and time.

Therefore, I would like to make some code which finds the second maximum and its depth, i.e. the depth of the maximum after the value stops decreasing from its first maximum.

```
x = [10, 8, 6, 8, 6, 4, 2]
depth = [100, 80, 60, 40, 20, 10, 5]

plt.plot(x,depth)
plt.ylabel('Depth')
plt.xlabel('Variable x')
```

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: first of all, when you talk about maximum, you need to switch x & y so that the chart is oriented correctly.  (depth = independent variable, Variable x = dependent variable).

Comment: secondly, do you guarantee there is only one maximum in the dataset ? or are there many ?

Comment: Thanks! And yes, there are only two maximums in the dataset.

Comment: in that respect, the question should ask: find the first maximum encountered...  confirm that is correct ?

Comment: This graphic and I think also your text don't fit together with the code snippet.
Could you maybe define a bit clearer, what "second maximum" means for you? Maybe it's just me, but I don't get it. In case you had two 10s in your x list, would we then just take the second? Or, like in the example, if there are two 8s is it the first, as 8 is not really the maximum anymore?

If you could just add one or two examples from which you want the "second maximum" and which is your expected output, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wording is a bit confusing, but i think you refer to finding the second local extremum (which can be a minimum or maximum). Try this code:

```
# we need a signum function
def sign(x):
    if x < 0: return -1
    elif x > 0: return 1
    else: return 0

def getNthLocalExtremum(x, depth, n):
    found = 1  # 'n' is made user friendly, starting at 1
    for i in range(1, len(depth) - 1):  # exclude the interval boundaries
        # we say either changing direction or not advancing in the
        # same direction is an local extremum
        if sign(x[i] - x[i-1]) * sign(x[i+1] - x[i]) != 1:  # (*)
            if n == found:
                return x[i], depth[i]  # the n-th extremum!
            else:
                found += 1  # advance looking for the next extremum

# get the 2nd extremum 
result = getNthLocalExtremum(x, depth, 2)
if result != None:
    print("extremum:", result)

>> extremum: (8, 20)
```

Your provided data and graph dont match btw, thus its `(8, 20)` in the data but `(8, 40)` in the graph. Regarding the check `(*)`: the idea is to detect a change in direction, which happens if two consecutive graph segments dont have the same direction sign.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry! I meant the second local extremum. This code is very helpful, thanks!